# parsing time string jQuery

Tags: jquery, string, parsing, time

I have a function which parses time strings, formatted as hh:mm (for example **18:45**).
Hours and minutes can be divided by colon, a blank space (**18 45**) or a comma (**18,45**).

The following variables split the time string if a colon is used:

```
var hourstart = parseInt(ini.substr(0, ini.indexOf(':')));
var minutestart = parseInt(ini.substr(ini.indexOf(":") + 1));
```

How can I make them work also when a blank space or a comma is used?
I tried with:

```
ini.indexOf(':'||' '||',')
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to also check if the string conforms to the format `digits`+`, .`+`digits`, you may use a [`/^(\d+)[ :,](\d+)$/`](https://regex101.com/r/eUvIt2/1) regex (or even [`/^(0?[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$/`](https://regex101.com/r/1URaD1/1)):

```js
var s = "18:45";
var m = s.match(/^(\d+)[ :,](\d+)$/);
if (m) {
  console.log("Hour: " + parseInt(m[1]));
  console.log("Minute: " + parseInt(m[2]));
}
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d+)` -  Group 1 (hours) capturing 1 or more digits
- `[ :,]` - a character class matching 1 single char: either a space, or `:` or `,`
- `(\d+)`  -  Group 2 (minutes) capturing 1 or more digits
- `$` -  end of string.

AND

- `(0?[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])` - captures hours from `00` to `23` with an optional leading `0` and
- `([0-5][0-9])` - captures minutes (from `00` to `59`)

Comment: Might want \d{1,2} / \d{2} rather than \d+.  Not clear from the question if 1am is 1:00 or 01:00

Comment: Well, following that path, it can even be `/^(0?[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$/`. That depends on the level of the input string "pre-validation".

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex to split with

```js
var time  = "18 45";

var parts = time.split(/[,\s\.\:]+/).map(Number);

var hours = parts.shift();
var mins  = parts.shift();

console.log(hours);
console.log(mins);
```

Comment: I added the colon char. It works. `var parts = ini.split(/[:,\s\.]+/).map(Number);`
`var hourstart = parseInt(parts.shift());`
`var minutestart  = parseInt(parts.shift());`

Comment: Forgot the colon, added it now. You don't have to parse the values, they are already integers, that's what the `.map(Number)` part does, it parses all the values as numbers.

Comment: Without `parseInt` it returned `NaN:NaN` value, after some computations on the hour/minute values.

Comment: @Alex - your code probably did, this does not, as there's nothing to parseInt, it's already numbers.

Comment: Sure adeneo. The issue was on my side. Thanks for your explanation.